# How to Put Two Sets of Data on One Graph in Excel

Tags: excel, charts, excel-charts

```
Date    Issue   redmeption  App     Date    Issue   redmeption  App 
21-Nov  891          200    523     28-Nov  660          179    302
22-Nov  607          125    423     29-Nov  712          165    420
23-Nov  456          165    422     30-Nov  499          128    331
24-Nov  510          115    391     1-Dec   596          170    392
25-Nov  525          120    400     2-Dec   573          169    397
26-Nov  585          158    396     3-Dec   450          120    350
27-Nov  582          88     410     4-Dec   650          150    360
```

Comment: What are you trying to show? Do you want continuous time on the x-axis? Are you trying to lay weeks over top one another?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating you chart with the x & y axis data then using the "add data" function in the chart menu.